# Change Text size as Button size change in Python Code Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, dropdown, kivy-language

I am a beginner in Kivy and currently working with Dropdowns in Kivy. Here is my code in that DropDown:

```
 def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MixedInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.dropdown_1 = DropDown()
    self.dropdown_1.max_height = 350
    for btn_1_index in substance_list:
        self.btn_1 = Button(text=str(btn_1_index), size_hint_y=None, height=44)
        self.btn_1.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.dropdown_1.select(btn.text))
        self.btn_1.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.set_up(btn.text))
        self.dropdown_1.add_widget(self.btn_1)
    self.mainbutton_1 = Button(text='Compound 1: Choose one from the list', size_hint=(0.5, 0.1), pos_hint={"x": 0, "y": 0.9}, font_size= 20)
    self.mainbutton_1.bind(on_release=self.dropdown_1.open)
    self.dropdown_1.bind(on_select=lambda instance, a: setattr(self.mainbutton_1, 'text', "Compound 1: " + a))
    self.add_widget(self.mainbutton_1)
```

So, if I want to change the font size of my mainbutton_1 as I resize the window, what can I do? I know that I cannot simply write like in a kv file:

```
font_size: self.width
```

Is there any way I can achieve this right on my Python code, not having to get into the kv file? Thank you for all your help.